# Weight any set of numbers to sum to zero in R

Tags: r, sum, weighted-average

I want to write a function in R that calculates weights to sum any set of numbers in R to zero. For example if

```
x <- c(-5, 6, 2, 4, -3)
```

I want a function that would return a new vector which has been weighted to force the vector sum to zero, by taking something off the positive numbers and adding something to the negative values...

**EDIT**: To clarify I do not want to shift values up or down a scale... I want to weight so that the rescaled negative numbers become slightly more/less negative and the rescaled positive numbers become slightly less/more positive.

I am not sure 1) how to go about calculating the right values for proportional weights and 2) if there is a function in R that can do it?

Comment: Use `x - mean(x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the sign after the rescaling...

```
x <- c(-5, -3, 0, 2, 4, 6, 50)

rescale_zero <- function(x){
  x1 <- x[x>0]
  x2 <- x[x<0]
  d <- (sum(x1) + sum(x2)) / 2
  w1 <- (sum(x1) - d) / sum(x1)
  w2 <- (sum(x2) - d) / sum(x2)
  y <- x
  y[x>0] <- x1*w1
  y[x<0] <- x2*w2
  y
}

rescale_zero(x) 
# [1] -21.875000 -13.125000   0.000000   1.129032   2.258065   3.387097  28.225806
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
x <- scale(x)
> x
           [,1]
[1,] -1.2450825
[2,]  1.1162809
[3,]  0.2576033
[4,]  0.6869421
[5,] -0.8157437
attr(,"scaled:center")
[1] 0.8
attr(,"scaled:scale")
[1] 4.658326
> sum(scale(x))
[1] 5.551115e-17
```

Edit:
As suggested by @Josh O'brien, setting scale = FALSE gives

```
scale(x, scale = FALSE)
     [,1]
[1,] -5.8
[2,]  5.2
[3,]  1.2
[4,]  3.2
[5,] -3.8
attr(,"scaled:center")
[1] 0.8
sum(scale(x, scale = FALSE))
[1] 6.661338e-16
```

Comment: You should probably set `scale(x, scale=FALSE)` so that it *just* centers (and doesn't also normalize the values by their (centered) standard deviation).

Answer (score 3):

**1) offsets** @jdharrison has already indicated if you want a vector `a` such that `sum(x-a)` is zero then setting `a` to be the mean of `x` will do it.

**2) weight vector** The wording of the question seems to ask for a weight vector `w` such that  `sum(w * x)` is zero.

**(i)** If `x` is not constant (i.e. its elements are not all the same) then in mathematical notation `P = I-xx'/(x'x)` is a projection orthogonal to `x` and `P1 = 1 - xx'1/(x'x`) is a vector in the range of `P` so switching to R code:

```
w <- 1 - x * sum(x) / sum(x*x)
```

is such a weight vector.  We can verify this:

```
> sum(w*x)
[1] 2.220446e-16
```

**(ii)** If `x` is constant but not identically zero then choose any non-constant vector `s <- seq_along(x)`, say.  Then `Ps = s - xx's/(x'x)` is orthogonal to `x` so:

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1, 1)
s <- seq_along(x)
w <- s - x * sum(s*x) / sum(x*x)
sum(w * x)
```

giving:

```
> sum(w * x)
[1] 0
```

Comment: thanks.. the second part with the weights was what i was after.... works with zeros :)

Comment: @g-grothendieck just playing around with this again... get some unexpected behavior with a large number... e.g.  x <- c(-5, -3, 0, 2, 4, 6, 20); rescale_zero <- function(x){ w <- 1 - x * sum(x) / sum(x*x); w*x }; rescale_zero(x) ... the 20 is rescaled to 0.4081 (smaller than the other +ve numbers?)

Comment: The resulting w is orthogonal to x which is all that is required.

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating @jdharrison's comment:

```
> x
[1] -5  6  2  4 -3
> sum(x)
[1] 4
> mean(x)
[1] 0.8
> x - mean(x)
[1] -5.8  5.2  1.2  3.2 -3.8
> sum(x - mean(x))
[1] 6.661338e-16 #floating point 0
```

So `x - mean(x)` will do the trick.